# execute an exe without knowing full path

Tags: batch-file, find, exe

I need to start an application by the name of Acad.exe without knowing its full path. this path is namly decide upon instalation by the person installing the app.

how can i achive this?

Comment: Ask the person installing the app to add it to PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is on the C: drive, you could do:

```
@echo off
c:
cd \
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b acad.exe') do set exeLcn=%%a
start %exeLcn%
```

Comment: try opening a command prompt and do "c:", then "cd \", then "dir /s /b acad.exe". A path should appear in the window. Do you get the path?

Comment: A couple of notes. 1. You can change both drive and directory with a single command: `CD /D C:\ `. 2. You don't need the `CD` command at all, as you can simply incorporate the starting path into the `DIR` command: `DIR /S /B C:\acad.exe`. 3. Assuming the folder for installing the product was chosen sanely, you could narrow down your search by using `%PROGRAMFILES%` instead of `C:\ `: `DIR /S /B "%PROGRAMFILES%\acad.exe"`.

Answer (score 3):

It is common for applications to store their install location in the registry, so the preferred way of finding them would be to look up the appropriate place in the registry. That way, you won't accidentally start a different program with the same file name.

Assuming `acad.exe` is AutoCAD, [this page gives the locations you have to look up](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Detecting_Autocad_current_version_and_path).

Answer (score 1):

Try this in any language that has an interface to the OLE2 layer:

```
CreateDispatch("Autocad.Application")
```

In C++:

```
::CoInitializeEx(NULL);
::CreateDispatch("AutoCAD.Application");
```

With a batch script:

- Save the following under the name `start_autocad.vbs

  ```
  set objShell=CreateObject("Autocad.Application")
  objShell.Visible = TRUE
  ```
- run `cscript start_autocad.vbs`.

Comment: The best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If this *acad.exe* installation follows the Windows convention, the installation process creates a special key in the registry :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

If *acad.exe* is defined there with required parameters then it's possible to start it from a batch file with this simple command :

```
START acad.exe
```

No need to specify the complete path, Windows will get it from the corresponding AppPath entry.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inventing your own method, you just might reproduce the behavior of CMD.EXE, looking for ACAD.EXE in the %PATH%.

try this as an example to get you started...

```
:inpath
echo %~$PATH:1
echo %~dp$PATH:1
goto :eof
```

invoke it this way

```
call :inpath acad.exe
```